# Classes, attributes and functions in lmfit library

Tags: python, class, object, lmfit

I have a general problem that I don't know how to navigate library modules to get the result that I want. Here is an example of what I mean:
Let's say I use lmfit library to do a fitting of a function:

```
from lmfit import Model, Parameters

#importing data

x=[-1.5933, -1.58, -1.5667, -1.5533, -1.54, -1.5267, -1.5133, -1.5, -1.4867, -1.4733, -1.46, -1.4467, -1.4333, -1.42, -1.4067, -1.3933, -1.38, -1.3667, -1.3533, -1.34, -1.3267, -1.3133, -1.3, -1.2867, -1.2733, -1.26, -1.2467, -1.2333, -1.22, -1.2067, -1.1933, -1.18, -1.1667, -1.1533, -1.14, -1.1267, -1.1133, -1.1, -1.0867, -1.0733, -1.06, -1.0467, -1.0333, -1.02, -1.0067, -0.9933, -0.98, -0.9667, -0.9533, -0.94, -0.9267, -0.9133, -0.9, -0.8867, -0.8733, -0.86, -0.8467, -0.8333, -0.82, -0.8067, -0.7933, -0.78, -0.7667, -0.7533, -0.74, -0.7267, -0.7133, -0.7, -0.6867, -0.6733, -0.66, -0.6467, -0.6333, -0.62, -0.6067, -0.5933, -0.58, -0.5667, -0.5533, -0.54, -0.5267, -0.5133, -0.5, -0.4867, -0.4733, -0.46, -0.4467, -0.4333, -0.42, -0.4067]

y=[0.0205, 0.0197, 0.0214, 0.0144, 0.0159, 0.0129, 0.0105, 0.0116, 0.0105, 0.0088, 0.0094, 0.0114, 0.009, 0.0102, 0.0099, 0.009, 0.0102, 0.0114, 0.0127, 0.011, 0.0134, 0.0143, 0.019, 0.0215, 0.0272, 0.0245, 0.0341, 0.0379, 0.0436, 0.0504, 0.0607, 0.0744, 0.0793, 0.0834, 0.1061, 0.1202, 0.1339, 0.1357, 0.1751, 0.1773, 0.1738, 0.1885, 0.201, 0.1995, 0.2058, 0.2039, 0.1893, 0.1856, 0.1693, 0.16, 0.1486, 0.1212, 0.1118, 0.0928, 0.0879, 0.0655, 0.0505, 0.0465, 0.039, 0.0308, 0.0304, 0.0259, 0.0221, 0.0205, 0.0212, 0.0196, 0.017, 0.0148, 0.0159, 0.0181, 0.0172, 0.0183, 0.0156, 0.0165, 0.0163, 0.0186, 0.0136, 0.0129, 0.0143, 0.0125, 0.0142, 0.0096, 0.0111, 0.0136, 0.0101, 0.0106, 0.009, 0.0094, 0.0079, 0.0081]


#creating params object from Parameters class
params=Parameters()

#writing initial parameters
params.add('a', value=-2.8e-04)
params.add('b', value=0.003)
params.add('int', value=0.2, min=0.01)
params.add('pos', value=-1, min=-1.2, max=0.8)
params.add('G', value=0.05, min = 0.005, max=0.5)

def gaussian(x, int1, pos1, G1):
    return int1*exp(-(x-pos1)**2/G1**2)


model = Model(gaussian)
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())
```

Now, if I want to specifically select one of the standard errors of the best fit results, I would do something like this:

```
result.params['a'].stderr
```

I know this is correct as I have tried it and it works, but I don't know how I can conclude this myself by reading the original library code. In the example above, is "result" an object of the Model class? Is stderr an attribute?

Thank you!

Comment: In order to know what `result` is, you have to read the documentation of the `Model.fit` method. It is its return value. `stderr` is an attribute of whatever `result.params['a']` is.

Comment: So method "fit" of the class "Model" is acting on object "model" to obtain "result"? What is the "result" then by definition? Another object? Thank you!

Comment: It's an object (as everything in Python is) of a particular type. Which type it is should be documented by the `Model.fit` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
from lmfit import Model
mymodel = Model(gaussian)
```

then `mymodel` is an instance of an `lmfit.Model`.  This object has a method called `fit`.  When you run that with

```
result = mymodel.fit(y, params, x=x)
```

then `result` is the value returned by `Model.fit`.  For `lmfit.Model.fit`, that return object is an instance of an `lmfit.model.ModelResult`.  In Python, you cannot really know what the object returned by any method will be except by a) running the method and inspecting the results, or b) reading the actual documentation for that method and seeing what it promises the return object will be **and** trusting that documentation **and** trusting that you did not get some exception raised while running that method.

The lmfit documentation for `Model.fit` does say and point to the return value will be a `ModelResult`.   It lists a pile of methods and attributes that this object will have.  You can also inspect all of this yourself at runtime with `type(result)` and `dir(result)`, which answer the questions of  "what kind of thing is `result`?" and "what things does this `result` have?".

For a `ModelResult`, one of the attributes it has is `params` which is an `lmfit.Parameters` object -- essentially a dictionary (+ a bit more that is not super-relevant here) with keys being "names of fitting parameters" and values being "fitting parameter objects".   This will match very closely the `params` you passed in (which is also an instance of `lmfit.Parameters`) but will have values and attributes updated to reflect the result of running the `fit method` -- the output Parameters. So

```
result.params['a']
```

is a lmfit `Parameter`, representing one of the values varied in a fit (though your model would not really have a Parameter named `a`, it would have Parameters with names `int1`, `pos1`, and `G1`).  This `lmfit.Parameter` object will have several attributes:  `value` for the parameter value (for the fit result, this will be the best-fit value), `stderr` with an estimate of the standard error, and several other attributes.  As before, you can read the documentation for what those attributes are or explore this and any other object with `dir()`.

None of this is particular to `lmfit`, it is just how Python works.  Everything is an object, some are "standard types", some are custom-built, some are simple, and some are complicated.  Objects have attributes (other objects). Some of those attributes are callable, and then called "methods".  Running methods will return other objects, though some return `None` which is kind of like not returning anything at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer, it helps a lot!